# Can't access Samba share on a different LAN

Tags: linux, network-shares, lan, samba

I have two different LANs in my home network, 192.168.0.1 (modem/switch) and 192.168.1.1 (router).

A switch is connected to the modem, it provides access to my PC, that's the 192.168.0.0/24 range. There's also a router connected to the modem, which provides wireless access to smartphones, tablets and another PC, that's the 192.168.1.0/24 range.

The wireless PC (192.168.1.x) can access the Samba share on the wired PC (192.168.0.x), but the wired PC can't access the Samba share in the wireless PC. The wireless PC can ping the wired PC, but the wired PC can't ping the wireless PC, or the router.

I read that I have to add a route to the system, so he can "see" the other network, but I didn't succeed in this task. I hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm running Debian Stretch on both computers, Samba is properly configured and the ports are open in the firewall of both systems.

**ip route** of the wired computer

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp3s0 proto static metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.3 metric 100
```

**ip route** of the wireless computer

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp1s0 proto static metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp1s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.187 metric 600
```

Comment: As always, the default gateway needs to be able to access *both* networks.

Comment: Can you add the output of `ip route` on both machines (wireless and wired) to your question?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That's what I'm asking how to do.

Comment: @xenoid Added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up cascading my router in LAN-to-LAN.

I pluged the cable that comes out of the LAN port of the modem in the LAN port of the router, instead of the WAN port, and disabled DHCP in the router. Now all devices are in the same LAN.

Answer (score 0):

And to explain *why* all devices need to be in the same LAN segment (no matter how you arrange your routers and switches to achieve this):

SMB is a broadcast protocol, that communicates by regularly sending broadcast packets. Unless you take explicit steps to route those packets between different LAN segements, or you explicitely use some other means to connect different LAN segments for SMB, that means that only devices in the same LAN segment (broadcast domain) will discover each other via SMB.